# Need help building a Flow on the 'Order Product' object?

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity

I have the requirement to sum all 'Unit Prices' for Order Products related to all Orders related an Opportunity.

Example-

Opportunity A has 2 Orders. Each Order has 2 Order Products. I need to add the Unit Prices of the 4 Order Products and display on the Opportunity record.

I was able to build a flow that references Order object pretty easily. This was because I could directly reference the OpportunityID. But my issue I'm facing with referencing the Order Product object, is there doesn't seem to be any direct relationship to the Opportunity object.

I was trying to make the Flow record triggered on the Order Product, so when the Unit Price changes, it will update the value on the opportunity but cant seem to make the connection between Opportunity and Opportunity Product.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to proceed here?

[image]

Comment: you need to rollup the Order Product to Order first; then you'll have fields on Order to rollup to Opportunity. Order->Order Product is Master-Detail so you can use RSF fields

Comment: Hey @cropredy. The 'Unit Price' field is not available when I rollup the Order Product to Order, and then Order to Opportunity. Only Discount, List Price, Quantity, Sales Price, and Total Price.

Comment: Use DLRS instead